# Refreshing a LinearLayout after adding a view

Tags: android, drawable, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to add views dynamically to a linearlayout.
I see through getChildCount() that the views are added to the layout, but even calling invalidate() on the layout doesn't give me the childs showed up.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Show us some code, as you might doing it wrong.

Comment: I Simply create a view, add it to the linearlayout and call invalidate().

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A couple of things you can check in your code:

- On the [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) that is being added, check that you call its [setLayoutParameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)) method with an appropriate [ViewGroup.LayoutParameter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).
- When you adding the new [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)s, make sure you are doing it on the UI thread. To do this, you can use the parent [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)'s [post](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post(java.lang.Runnable)) method.

This self contained example adds a [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) after a short delay when it starts:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProgrammticView extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        setContentView(layout);

        // This is just going to programatically add a view after a short delay.
        Timer timing = new Timer();
        timing.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final TextView child = new TextView(ProgrammticView.this);
                child.setText("Hello World!");
                child.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                // When adding another view, make sure you do it on the UI
                // thread.
                layout.post(new Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        layout.addView(child);
                    }
                });
            }
        }, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I make new shapes inside a Handler.
The weird fact is that the first shape is drawn on the linearlayout, but the next ones not.

Comment: check that u have added android:orientation="vertical" to LinearLayout

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and noticed that my overriden onMeasure() method wasn't called after the invalidate. So I created my own subroutine in the LinearLayout and called it before the invalidate() method.

Here is the code for an vertical LinearLayout:

```
private void measure() {
    if (this.getOrientation() == LinearLayout.VERTICAL) {
        int h = 0;
        int w = 0;
        this.measureChildren(0, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < this.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = this.getChildAt(i);
            h += v.getMeasuredHeight();
            w = (w < v.getMeasuredWidth()) ? v.getMeasuredWidth() : w;
        }
        height = (h < height) ? height : h;
        width = (w < width) ? width : w;
    }
    this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

Comment: where did you get height , width?

Answer (score 1):

I spent a lot of time to solve this problem too. And I found a simple method of refresh LinearLayout in 3 lines of code

You must set transperent color in style.xml

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```

And in the code just call to set background

```
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.noteList);
ll.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
ll.invalidate();
```

If you has drawable background call

```
ll.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.your_drawable);
```