# my Custom View gets drawn only when added in onCreate

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-component, android-custom-view

I made a "GraphBar" custom view that is a `RelativeLayout` with a `TextView` on the bottom and an `ImageView`, varying in height, above that. Here is the code:

```
public class GraphBar extends RelativeLayout {

    private int mAvailHeight; // space for the bar (component minus label)
    private float mBarHeight; // 0.0-1.0 value

    public GraphBar(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public GraphBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public GraphBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.graphbar, this, true);
        setId(R.id.graphBar); // defined in <merge> but not assigned (?)
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        mAvailHeight = getHeight()-findViewById(R.id.label).getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        View bar2 = findViewById(R.id.smallBar);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams llp2 = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) bar2.getLayoutParams();
        llp2.height = Math.round((float)mAvailHeight * mBarHeight);
    }

    public void setBarHeight(float value, float max) {
        mBarHeight = value / max;
        findViewById(R.id.smallBar).requestLayout();
    }

    public void setLabel(CharSequence c) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.label)).setText(c);
    }
}
```

While adding these GraphBars and setting their height in `onCreate()` works well, if I create them onClickSomething or call again `setBarHeight()` on the created bars, the only way to see changes is Load View Hierarchy. I've been told [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4150446/503900) that it means I need to call somewhere `requestLayout()`. Where else than after modifying `mBarHeight`? Any help? I tried everywhere, and with `invalidate()` too.

Thank you,
Andrea

(if you need I can post the activity with which i do my tests and the graphbar.xml)

---

I've found it's probably [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6089). The workaround should be, again, calling `requestLayout()`. Still i don't understand where i can put the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found a way to call again `requestLayout()`. I called `setWillNotDraw(false)` in the constructor so that in `onDraw()` (that is after `onLayout()`) I can call the extra `requestLayout()`. This generates a stupid cycle but solves the problem aesthetically.

**If anyone knows a better solution, let me know...** here the new code (modifies are next to comments):

```
//...
    public GraphBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.graphbar, this, true);
        setWillNotDraw(false); // WORKAROUND: onDraw will be used to make the
                                // redundant requestLayout() call
        setId(R.id.graphBar);
    }
//...
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // i think it's one of the worst workaround one could think of.
        // luckily android is smart enough to stop the cycle...
        findViewById(R.id.smallBar).requestLayout();
    }

    public void setBarHeight(float value, float max) {
        mBarHeight = value / max;
        View bar =   findViewById(R.id.smallBar);

        bar.requestLayout(); // because when we create this view onDraw is called...
        bar.invalidate();    // ...but not when we modify it!!!
                            //so we need to invalidate too
    }
//...
```