# MonoDroid custom View doesn't show child

Tags: android, custom-controls, xamarin.android

I have pretty simple custom view:

```
public class TestControl : RelativeLayout
{
    private readonly Context _context;

    private TextView _textLabel;

    public TestControl(Context context) : base(context)
    {
        _context = context;

        LayoutParameters = new LayoutParams(300, 200);
        SetBackgroundColor(Color.Green);

        _textLabel = new TextView(_context);
        _textLabel.SetText("Test test test test test test", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        _textLabel.SetTextColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
        _textLabel.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(200, 50);
        _textLabel.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);

        AddView(_textLabel);
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {

    }
}
```

When I try to add it as a view into my main activity layout:

```
var myControl = new TestControl(this);
myMainLayout.AddView(myControl);
```

I see only green recangle(300 x 200) but no TextView.

What am I doing wrong? Any help on how to show at least TextView inside some colored layout much appreciated, as I need actualy much more complicated custom view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to do something similar to what's explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163918/my-custom-view-gets-drawn-only-when-added-in-oncreate). [SetWillNotDraw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setWillNotDraw%28boolean%29) can play some tricks on you in such circumstances.