# Android: HorizontalScrollview content not getting updated Dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

We are facing an issue with HorizontalScrollview content not getting updated dynamically. At the first time call to the below function set the scrollview content correctly (Called from onCreate). But from the next time onwards the layout is not getting updated (basically calling the function after some new downloads are done on the background service). playlist_scroll is the HorizontalScrollView in which we are having the LinearLayout playlist_content to which the items (inflated from partial_main_playlist) are added.

```
HorizontalScrollView playlist_scroll = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.playlist_scroll);
LinearLayout playlist_content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.playlist_content);

 private void setPlaylistNameScroll(List<Playlist> result) {
    if (result != null && result.size() > 0) {
        playlist_row_position = 0;
        playlists = result;
        playlist_content.removeAllViews();
        for (Playlist playlist : playlists) {
            playlist_ll = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.partial_main_playlist, playlist_content, false);
            playlist_ll.setTag(playlist.getId());
            Log.d(TAG, "setPlaylistNameScroll - playlist " + playlist.getName());
            if (border != null && !border.equals("")) {
                playlist_ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#" + border));
            }
            playlist_row = (LinearLayout) playlist_ll.findViewById(R.id.playlist_row);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams playlist_row_params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) playlist_row.getLayoutParams();
            playlist_row_params.width = playlist_row_width;
            playlist_row_params.height = playlist_row_height;
            playlist_row.setLayoutParams(playlist_row_params);
            playlist_row_item = (LinearLayout) playlist_ll.findViewById(R.id.playlist_row_item);
            if (playlist_bg_bitmap_draw != null) {
                playlist_row_item.setBackground(playlist_bg_bitmap_draw);
            }
            playlist_tv = (TextView) playlist_ll.findViewById(R.id.playlist_tv);
            String _playlist_name = playlist.getName();
                playlist_tv.setText(_playlist_name);
            playlist_tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#" + playlist_title_color));
            playlist_ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            v.startAnimation(btn_click_animation);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
                    playlist_content.addView(playlist_row, playlist_row_position++);

        }
        playlist_scroll.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if(playlist_content.getParent() != null)
                {
                    ((ViewGroup)playlist_content.getParent()).removeView(playlist_content);
                }
                playlist_scroll.addView(playlist_content);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

the partial_main_playlist.xml is as follows

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/playlist_row"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="playlistClicked"
    android:background="@color/colorDefaultBg">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/playlist_row_item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/resource_row_margin"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/playlist_tv"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Playlist"
            android:textColor="@color/colorDefaultText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/playlist_scroll_title_font" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/playlist_status"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:src="@drawable/shuffle"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[We have referred the answer here and implemented the above code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469466/refreshing-a-linearlayout-after-adding-a-view)

setPlaylistNameScroll method is invoked from the DownloadService on ReceiveResult like this

```
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    String error;
    switch (resultCode) {
        case DownloadService.STATUS_RUNNING:
            media_syncing = true;
            Log.d(TAG, "DownloadService.STATUS_RUNNING");
            break;
        case DownloadService.STATUS_FINISHED:
            Log.d(TAG, "DownloadService.STATUS_FINISHED");
            setPlaylistNameScroll(databaseHandler.getDevicePlaylists(device_id, playlist_ordering));
            break;
        case DownloadService.STATUS_ERROR:
            media_syncing = false;
            error = resultData.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            Log.d(TAG, "DownloadService.STATUS_ERROR " + error);
            break;
        case DownloadService.STATUS_STOPPED:
            media_syncing = false;
            error = resultData.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            Log.d(TAG, "DownloadService.STATUS_STOPPED " + error);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing you mentioned about horizontal scroll view in your code.

Comment: @chandil03 Sorry, playlist_scroll is the HorizontalScrollView, in which we have a Linearlayout playlist_content to which we are adding the items. Please see my edited question.

Comment: where is your downloading code? or the code where you are updating content in linearLayout inside scrollView.

Comment: @chandil03 we omit the download code as the question will become too lengthy. The call to the method setPlaylistNameScroll from the DownloadService which is an IntentService is coming (we can see the logs which confirms it) . The scroll content and linearlayout content are updated like playlist_content.addView(playlist_row, playlist_row_position++); and finally playlist_scroll.post(new Runnable() {
 public void run() { if(playlist_content.getParent() != null) { ((ViewGroup)playlist_content.getParent()).removeView(playlist_content); } playlist_scroll.addView(playlist_content);  } });

Comment: I am telling to put all the code but just resultReceiver where method is getting called. I did not get what are you trying to do in your playlist_scroll.post method. I mean with this much of code i cant suggest you a solution.

Comment: @chandil03 Please see my edit.

Comment: are you sure setPlaylistNameScroll method is getting called? And what post method is doing in the last of your setPlaylistNameScroll mthod.

Comment: @chandil03 yes setPlaylistNameScroll is getting called, the logs are coming. When Applied post on parent with reference to the link attached as add view alone was not working, we was trying the answer in the link

Comment: have you debugged this, did you check child count to make sure they are getting added in linear layout?

Comment: @chandil03 Yes the child count gives 19 or so but we can see only 2 children in it, which was loaded initially

Comment: I would suggest you to change horizontal scroll view to vertical and set linearLaytou's orientation to vertical and check if problem still persists.

Comment: @chandil03 I will try and update....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have read in google doc, other tutorials that any Update to the horizontalscrollview content should happen from the UI thread. So we set the receiver like

```
mReceiver = new DownloadResultReceiver(new Handler());     
mReceiver.setReceiver(this);
```

As per my understanding "new Handler()" will make sure that the result receiver method calls will execute in the UI thread. But unfortunately this was not the case in our case atleast in Android 5.1.1 API Level 22, other version we haven't observed this issue. Finally we ended up in something like a runnable which will contantly check if there is a new version if so it will update the horizontal Scrollview

```
Runnable refreshChecker = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            int save_media_called = databaseHandler.getSave_media_called();                               
            if (save_media_called_log != save_media_called && save_media_called != 0) {                    setPlaylistNameScroll(databaseHandler.getDevicePlaylists(device_id, playlist_ordering));
                save_media_called_log = save_media_called;
            }
        } finally {
            refreshHandler.postDelayed(refreshChecker, refresh_check_interval);
            refresh = true;
        }
    }
};
```